# BLE readCharacteristic(characteristic) returns false (Accu Check Instant Gluco Meter)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read existing (device has reading) and new characteristic from BLE device. Once pair is successful `onServicesDiscovered` called and here i checked for service UUID is for Glucose Measurement.

If true I am calling:
`gatt.readCharacteristic(gattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")))`

But this method always returns false therefore `onCharacteristicRead()` never gets called. I have checked `characteristic.getProperties()` returns value 16. BluetoothGatt API method which returns `false`

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());

            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                for (BluetoothGattService gattService : services) {
                    String serviceUUID = gattService.getUuid().toString();
                    if (serviceUUID.equals(UUID_GLUCOSE_MEASUREMENT.toString())) {
                        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead ", "" + characteristic.getUuid());
                            if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))){
                                Log.i("onCharacteristicRead ", "Match Glocuse ");                                                                  
                                boolean isRead = gatt.readCharacteristic(gattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")));
                                Log.i("onCharacteristicRead ", "" + isRead);                                                  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());

            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", "" + (data == null ? "NULL" : "NON NULL"));

            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for(byte byteChar : data) {
                    Log.i("onCharacteristicRead ", "" + byteChar);
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                }
                binding.tvHexCharacteristic.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                //Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", stringBuilder.toString());
                //Convert byte[] to String
                String value = new String(data);
                binding.tvCharacteristic.setText(value);
                Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", value);
            }

            //Trigger Notification
            //gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            //gatt.disconnect();
        }
    };
```

Is there any solution or idea why its happening. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Please post more code. Are you sure you don't already have a pending GATT operation while you send the read request?

Comment: Please check updated code. I can see if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))) executes once. I dont think there is any pending gatt. If there, then how to identify and whats the solution for that

Comment: First check `gattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))` actually gets a characteristic. Then if it does it is a reading error. Which could be permissions set by the other device on the ble settings. You will need to ensure that characteristic has the attribute of a readable characteristic.